# Multiple Choice Quiz not acknowledging answer

Tags: java, android

Whenever I run the app, it will give me a toast saying correct or try again, but the toast doesn't match what it should. 
For example correct items have shown a toast of try again, and incorrect have shown a toast of correct. 
I have tried all different variations to try and fix the code and then they all end up incorrect or it marks them all as correct.
Can't figure out what I'm missing.
Any help is appreciated, I'm new but trying.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private QuestionList mathQuestionList = new QuestionList();
private TextView scoreView;
private Button questionView;
private Button imageAnswerSpace;
private Button imageChoice1;
private Button imageChoice2;
private Button imageChoice3;
private int theAnswer;
private int theScore = 0;
private int theQuestionNumber = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    ImageButton questionViewButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.questionView);
    ImageButton imageAnswerSpace = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    final ImageButton imageChoice1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final ImageButton imageChoice2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    final ImageButton imageChoice3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    imageChoice1.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    imageChoice2.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    imageChoice3.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

    imageAnswerSpace.setOnDragListener(dragListener);

    updateQuestion();
}


//(outside of onCreate)

View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, myShadowBuilder, v, 0);

        return true;
    }
};

View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int dragEvent = event.getAction();
        final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

        switch (dragEvent) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                //imageview1 clicked and correct
                if ((view.getId() == (R.id.imageView1)) == (v.getId() == theAnswer)) {
                    Log.v("MyActivity", "imageview1 is correct");
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    //imageview1 clicked and not correct
                } else if ((view.getId() == (R.id.imageView1)) != (view.getId() == theAnswer)) {
                    Log.v("MyActivity", "imageview1 not correct");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();


                    //imageview2 clicked and correct
                } else if ((view.getId() == (R.id.imageView2)) == (v.getId() == theAnswer)) {
                    Log.v("MyActivity", "imageview2 is correct");
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    //imageview2 clicked and not correct
                } else if ((view.getId() == (R.id.imageView2)) != (view.getId() == theAnswer)) {
                    Log.v("MyActivity", "imageview2 not correct");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();


                    //imageview3 clicked and correct
                } else if ((view.getId() == (R.id.imageView3)) == (v.getId() == theAnswer)) {
                    Log.v("MyActivity", "imageview3 is correct");
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    //imageview3 clicked and not correct
                } else if ((view.getId() == (R.id.imageView3)) != (view.getId() == theAnswer)) {
                    Log.v("MyActivity", "imageview3 not correct");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }

        }
        return true;
    }

};



private void updateQuestion() {

    ImageView changeQuestion = findViewById(R.id.questionView);
    changeQuestion.setImageResource(mathQuestionList.getQuestion(theQuestionNumber));

    ImageView changeImage1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    changeImage1.setImageResource(mathQuestionList.getChoice1(theQuestionNumber));

    ImageView changeImage2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    changeImage2.setImageResource(mathQuestionList.getChoice2(theQuestionNumber));

    ImageView changeImage3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    changeImage3.setImageResource(mathQuestionList.getChoice3(theQuestionNumber));


    theAnswer = mathQuestionList.getCorrectAnswer(theQuestionNumber);


    if (theQuestionNumber < 4) {
        theQuestionNumber++;
    } else if (theQuestionNumber == 4) {
        theQuestionNumber = 0;
    }

}


private void updateScore(int point) {
    // scoreView.setText("" + theScore);
}
}
```

layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/questionView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/questionmark"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    `enter code here`</LinearLayout>
```

answers

```
public class QuestionList {

public static int[] mathQuestions = new int[]{
        R.drawable.image35,
        R.drawable.image23,
        R.drawable.image44,
        R.drawable.image15,
        R.drawable.image26
};

public static int mathOptions [][] = {
        {R.drawable.number4, R.drawable.number2, R.drawable.number8},
        {R.drawable.number5, R.drawable.number1, R.drawable.number7},
        {R.drawable.number4, R.drawable.number6, R.drawable.number8},
        {R.drawable.number7, R.drawable.number6, R.drawable.number3},
        {R.drawable.number9, R.drawable.number5, R.drawable.number8}
};

public static int[] mathCorrectAnswers = new int[]{
        R.drawable.number8,
        R.drawable.number5,
        R.drawable.number8,
        R.drawable.number6,
        R.drawable.number8
};


public int getQuestion(int a) {
    int question = mathQuestions[a];
    return question;
}


public int getChoice1(int a) {
    int choice0 = mathOptions[a][0];
    return choice0;
}


public int getChoice2(int a) {
    int choice1 = mathOptions[a][1];
    return choice1;
}

public int getChoice3(int a) {
    int choice2 = mathOptions[a][2];
    return choice2;
}

public int getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
    int answer = mathCorrectAnswers[a];
    return answer;
}
}
```

Comment: ok, good to know. I'm just confused on how I compare them. And the view vs. v, i've been trying to play with the code so much I forgot to switch it so that it's all the same. sorry

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your app.